# Jquery - How to defer default behaviour of an event?

Tags: jquery, forms, preventdefault

I have function to handle submit event for a form.

What I want to do inside the handler is to defer the default behavior until an Ajax function has finished running.

Example code

```
$("#some_form").on("submit", function(event){
    // Defer default event behavior

    // Do some ajax function with a callback function to run
    // after it is finished as an argument
    ajaxFunction(function(){
        // Do some stuff

        // Let the default event behavior that was deferred to be run
    });
});
```

Is there a way to do this?

EDIT:

The Ajax code is just an example. I could have done it like this

```
$("#some_form").on("submit", function(event){
        // Defer default event behavior

        // Do some stuff

        // Let the default event behavior that was deferred to be run
});
```

Comment: you can probably try using return false; statement at the end of the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can cancel the form submission with `event.preventDefault()`. Then submit the form when the ajax is completed, use a flag to know the ajax is completed or not.

```
$("#some_form").on("submit", function(event){
    if (!$(this).data('ajax-complete')){
        event.preventDefault();
        // Defer default event behavior        
        // Do some ajax function with a callback function to run
        // after it is finished as an argument
        ajaxFunction(function(){
            // Do some stuff

            // submit the form in the ajax success function
            $("#some_form").data('ajax-complete', true).submit();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: The problem I see with the solution of triggering a submit event is that it will make this event handler run again, thereby creating a loop.

Comment: @arvinsim `$(this).data('ajax-complete')` checks if the ajax was completed

Answer (score 0):

For a specific call use the success property of the ajax object. (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/test.html',
  success: function(data) {
    $("#some_form").submit();
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't think that my problem is an Ajax problem. The problem is how to defer default behaviour and also let the deferred behaviour run. Whether there is Ajax in the code or not is not really relevant. It is just for example.

Comment: OK tnx! Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to submit the form after the default behavior has been prevented (deferred) like :

```
$("#some_form").on("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // do something
    console.log("do something");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
    //  url : "example.php",
    }).done(function() {
        console.log("success");
    }).fail(function() {
        console.log("error");
    });
});
```

Check **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SUSLc/)**

Comment: Wouldn't this cause the event handler to go on a loop? When you trigger submit, wouldn't it call this event handler again?

Comment: @arvinsim : the event handler is not triggering submit but submitting the form once (check the console logs in demo)

Comment: I need to trigger submit in the end

Comment: @arvinsim : you don't need to trigger submit because `$.ajax` does submit the form (after you do whatever you want to do first). I have the impression that you are having troubles understanding how this works :/