# How can I run onclick event from the assigned variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a different scenario of a submit button - submit the info if the response is correct, and throw an error if the response is incorrect.

First, I store the submit button `onclick` event in a variable and make it `null`, so it will not submit the info if the response is incorrect.

Here is my code:

```
(function() {
    var submitBtn = jQuery('#submitConfigBtn')[0]
    var submitBtnOnclick = submitBtn.onclick
    submitBtn.onclick = null

    jQuery('#submitConfigBtn').click(function() {
        var btn = jQuery(this);

        ...ajax call,
            success: function(response) {

                if (response === 'badresponse') {
                    console.log('Bad response')
                } else {
                    console.log('Response is ok')
                    btn.onclick = submitBtnOnclick
                    btn.click();
                }

            },
            err: function(err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
        });
    })
})()
```

How I can retrieve the event from the variable and run it inside the `onclick` function?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the "standard action" to happen you can call `event.preventDefault()` inside your click-handler function. There is no need to delete and re-install the on-click function itself.

Furthermore the jquery element `btn` will not know what to do with the property "onclick". This would be a property of a DOM object.

You are not the first person to come up with this problem ;-)
See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/14154017/2610061 for a possible solution.

(It looks like you have to know *which* action you want to defer, as there is no standard way of belatedly triggering *any* action that was initially prevented from happening. You can only trigger specific actions like `.submit()` of a form.)

I prepared a scenario that would work for your requirements. Please note that I do *not capture* the "click" event on the actual *button* but instead I listen for the "submit" event on the surrounding *form*. The form can be submitted by either clicking the button or by hitting the return key after filling out the input field. The current event handler will be executed in either case!

At first the default action is prevented from happening, then an asynchronous Ajax call is sent. Its success function in `.done()` carries out some "meaningful" test on the response and - depending on its outcome - will then trigger the form's submission or not. Should the Ajax call itself fail the `.fail()` function jumps into action and will do whatever is required ...

```js
$(function() {
 $('.validatedForm').on('submit', function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault(); // prevent submission before AJAX call
  $.getJSON('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/'+$('#q').val())
   .done(function(da){
     console.log(da);
     if (da.address.city!=="Howemouth") { // some meaningful test on the result ...
       setTimeout(()=>ev.target.submit(), 3000); // belated form submission!
       console.log('Hey, the input was changed, in 3 seconds I will go to google!')
     }})
   .fail(function(da){console.log(da.status, da.statusText,'- Only user-IDs 1 ... 10 are allowed.');});
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="http://google.com"  class="validatedForm">
 <input name="q" id="q" value="7">
 <button>submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: thank you, it's far more understandable and precise :) but how can I later trigger the onclick event? `$(this).click()`?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, you want to submit the form if the response is okay. No need to store the `onclick` event just to stop the form from submitting, you can either use: [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault), or use `type="button"` instead in your button

I used the latter here, so instead of invoking the click event of the button, you need to use [`.submit()`](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) to the form, like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.submitConfigBtn').on('click', function() {
    //ajax part here
    //sample response result
    let response = 'badresponse';
    if (response === 'badresponse') {
      console.log('Bad response')
    } else {
      console.log('Response is ok')
      $('.sampleForm').submit();
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="sampleForm" action="" method="POST">
  <button type="button" class="submitConfigBtn">Submit Config Button</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you do some tricky logic.

Step 1.
Use two button 
1. Submit type 
2. Button type

Step 2.
Hide the submit button always.

Step 3.

```
if(response == true){
 $("submitbtnid").trigger('click');
}
else {
 console.log('write your custom logic');
}
```